# Check specific day greater than 30 days from today using php

Tags: php

I tried to find out difference between today date and specific day with format `Ymd`.
How to check whether specific day is greater than 30 days from today?

For example:

```
$date1 = '20160315'; // 2016-03-15
$date2 = '20160115'; // 2016-01-15
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$date1=date_create('20160315');
$date2=date_create('20160115');
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
$days = $diff->format("%a");

if($days > 30) do something
```

Comment: - Exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So simple...

```
$date1 = '20160315'; // 2016-03-15
$date2 = date(Ymd); // 2016-01-15

$day_difference = $date1  - $date2 
if($day_difference > 30) {
 echo 'specific day is greater than 30 days from today';
} else {
 echo 'specific day is less than 30 days from today';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-11-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$int = $interval->format('%R%a');

if($int > +30) {
    echo "Greater than 30 days";
} else {
    echo "Less than 30 days";

}
```